# Returning second and third record

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I am using mongoid_nested_set, how can I simplify this code:

```
category.ancestors.where(depth: 3).first
```

previously I used:

```
category.ancestors[3]
```

But this doesn't seem to work in mongoid 3.1.5 / rails 3.2.13 / ruby 1.9.3 / acticeadmin-mongoid 0.3.0

Comment: It should work. What's happening?

Comment: If I run 'category.ancestors[3]'
I am getting a runtime error and the error says only '3'

Comment: `ancestors` is not a Mongoid method, please specify the gem you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the culprit was acticeadmin_mongoid 0.3.0, I have removed it and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the ancestry-gem?

If you do, you could use their named-scopes
In this case

```
category.ancestors.to_depth(3) # Return nodes up to depth 3 (1 and 2 also included)
category.ancestors.at_depth(depth) # Return nodes with the exact depth of 3
```

As seen in the [README](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry#selecting-nodes-by-depth).

Comment: Unfortunately I am using mongoid_nested_set, however this would be perfect if I was using ancestry. Thanks